# Import .json to Database

Tags: python, json, sqlite, ipython

I successfully downloaded tweets into a json file. Now I try to import it in a database with this function:

```
def import_json(fi):

logging.warning("Loading tweets from json file {0}".format(fi))
for line in open(fi, "rb"):
    data = json.loads(line.decode('utf-8'))
    database.create_tweet_from_dict(data)
```

the json-file "keywords_BVBS04.json" lays in a folder called *data* which is in the current directory. The function is in a file called *BVBS04.py*

to start the import I type *BVBS04.import_json(keywords_BVBS04.json)* in ipython in the console. this is what I get back:

> NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>   ----> 1 BVBS04.import_json(keywords_BVBS04.json)
>
> NameError: name 'keywords_BVBS04' is not defined

Now here comes the  is a beginner's question: Where/how do I have to define "keywords_BVBS04"? I tried a lot :(

Thanks!

Comment: Import into **what** database?

Comment: I wouldn't convert it to a dict, I would store it into the db as a LOB field.

Comment: into a peewee sqlite database. it appears automatically. as 'tweets.db'

Comment: Alright. Just know you have to parse out the JSON into columns. Or use an actually database meant for JSON document storage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you want,

1) you need to `import` the function `from` the script, not use dot-notation on the script.

2) Quote the filename.

```
>>> from BVBS04 import import_json
>>> import_json("keywords_BVBS04.json")
```

Good luck with the rest of things

Comment: thanks. sorry, I am social scientist getting familiar with a script I got from a colleague. Now I finally get another error and am will think about it:)